# Reformatting DOB in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column called `DOB` that has dates of birth in them but in a poorly formatted version. Some are standard like `12/23/1987`, some are `1/2/1976` and some `10/3/1988` and `3/12/1954` type formatting.

I'd like to make them all standard like `01/03/1987`, so basically all in a `mm/dd/yyyy` format. Any ideas?

Comment: So it's a varchar field, which holds date values as strings, but in multiple different formats?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: If they are **dates**, then you should store them in a `DATE` or `DATETIME` column type - which has **no format** - it's just an 8-byte binary that represents a date properly

Comment: yes its a varchar field that hold all variations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this....

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @Dates TABLE( DOB  VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @Dates VALUES
('12/23/1987'),   ('1/2/1976'),
('3/12/1954'),    ('10/3/1988')
```

### Query

```
SELECT DOB 
      ,CASE WHEN ISDATE(DOB) = 1 
              THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(DOB AS DATETIME), 101) 
            ELSE NULL 
       END AS Formatted  
FROM @Dates
```

### Result

```
╔════════════╦════════════╗
║    DOB     ║ Formatted  ║
╠════════════╬════════════╣
║ 12/23/1987 ║ 12/23/1987 ║
║ 1/2/1976   ║ 01/02/1976 ║
║ 3/12/1954  ║ 03/12/1954 ║
║ 10/3/1988  ║ 10/03/1988 ║
╚════════════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: then ouch, Well there cant any Correct solution for a Wrong Problem (In this case wrong schema) :) . I think everyone would agree with me on this, op needs to fix his schema rather then finding a solution to clean up the mess created by this poor schema :S

Comment: Well, he needs some kind of (partial) solution. He can't just delete the column or go home.

Comment: Thanks guys. Yeah this was inherited by me so I didn't get to create it but rather have to fix other persons poor planning. Thank you for the responses. I'll give that a shot and repost :-)

Comment: Yes but will need a script that will execute and update command to permanently reformat the mess that it is in there if possible...

Comment: In fox pro this works. any way to convert to tsql?  replace all date_of_bi with "0"+ALLT(date_of_bi) for !"/" $ SUBSTR(ALLT(date_of_bi),3,1)

replace all date_of_bi with LEFT(ALLT(date_of_bi),3)+"0"+SUBSTR(ALLT(date_of_bi),4) for !"/" $ SUBSTR(ALLT(date_of_bi),6,1)